# user control properties

Tags: asp.net, linq

i have a detail view with below markup and data source of this detail view is from stored procedure "spDocResult" like below:

```
select DocId,TransId,FileId,Filename,ContentType,Data,DocumentNo,Title,TRANSMITTAL
from DocumentSum2
where (DocId=@Docid)AND(Transid=@Transid)
```

one field of this detail view should be show Efile Names so i have made 1 user control for that

```
public partial class FileTemp : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private EDMSDataContext _DataContext;
private IEnumerable<tblFile> _Efiles;

public IEnumerable<tblFile> Efiles
{
    set { _Efiles = value; }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
}
    protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Download")
    {
         _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();
        //you can get your command argument values as follows
        string FileId = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
       int _FileId = Convert.ToInt32(FileId);
       tblFile Efile = (from ef in _DataContext.tblFiles
                    where ef.FileId == _FileId
                    select ef).Single();
       if (Efile != null)
       {

           download(Efile);

       }}}

        private void download ( tblFile Efile)
```

{

```
Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])Efile.Data.ToArray();
Response.Clear();

Response.Buffer = true;

Response.Charset = "";

Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Response.ContentType = Efile.ContentType.ToString();

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="

+ Efile.FileName.ToString());

Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);

Response.Flush();

Response.End();
```

}

```
public override void DataBind()
        {
            base.DataBind();
            GridViewEfile.DataSource = _Efiles;
            GridViewEfile.DataBind();

        }
```

}

now i have problem because datasource of detailview comes from a stored procedure and properties of user control is from tblFile, so when i use DetailsView1_DataBound i do not know how i have to get user control properties.when i use below code, i have error

```
can not implicity convert type string to system.collection.generic.iEnumerable<tblfile>
```

i have error for this line

```
fileList.Efiles = docresult.Filename;

protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    spDocResultResult docresult = (spDocResultResult)DetailsView1.DataItem;
    FileTemp fileList = (FileTemp)DetailsView1.FindControl("FileTemp1");

    fileList.Efiles = docresult.Filename;
    fileList.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: So from what I gathered, the detailview is being databound to some items from a stored proc, but the detailview also contains a user control that needs to be bound to something else?

Comment: yes, i need file names in usercontrol but when i use docresult.Filename, i have error implicity convert.so i do not know i have to change property usercotrol or datailview datasouse to something else except this stored proc

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a data binding issue at all. It's a little hard to gather from the context, but...

```
FileTemp fileList = (FileTemp)DetailsView1.FindControl("FileTemp1");    
fileList.Efiles = docresult.Filename;
```

Is fileList.Efiles a list of items that you just want to assign a file name to? If so, you might just need to foreach through them.

```
foreach (var file in fileList.Efiles)
{
    file.FileName = docresult.Filename;
}
```

Also, add this line to your Efiles declaration to solve the Get accessor error.

```
public IEnumerable<tblFile> Efiles
{
    get { return _Efiles; } // <- here
    set { _Efiles = value; }
}
```

Comment: tblfile is the the table with this columns.(fileid,DocId,TransId,FileName,ContentType,Data),

Comment: Ah, ok that helps. I adjusted my answer a little.
If the FileName is the only field you need to adjust, that ought to do the trick.

Comment: thanks, i have error for (fileList.Efiles) the property or indexer 'filetemp.Efiles' cannot be used in this context because it lacks to get accessor

Comment: error removed but user control field that should show filename, shows nothing

Comment: When you put a break point in your DataBind() method, does _Efiles display the correct file names? If so, could it be an order of Postback issue where the detailview completes its postback before your control renders with the new information?

Comment: i did it and seems DetailsView1_DataBound does not work at all. so i cut and paste codes from there to page_load, now i have error (object reference not to set an instance of an object) for (fileList.Efiles)

Comment: @masoud: If this answer helped you solve your original issue, you should mark it as accepted.  If you have another issue, make another question.  We can't troubleshoot your issue without seeing current code.